# Is it Possible to use Click Once Deployment with F#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, clickonce

I was going to use Click Once for my F# project but it seems this is not supported within VS2010 - is there a way to make it work?  If not, what would be an alternative?

The application will be used by Sales people on Windows 7 Tablets with no internet connection.

My thinking was to use ClickOnce so that they could check for updates each morning / evening (where they have internet) before going off to do Sales (no internet)

Comment: If this is a feature you very strongly want to see in future versions of Visual Studio, you can vote for it here: `http://visualstudio.uservoice.com`

Answer (score 5):

There's no integrated IDE-level support for ClickOnce in F# projects, however...

One possible approach is to ship a C# app via ClickOnce, but put all of your important logic in an F# project which is then referenced by the (mostly-empty) C# shell. I've done this several times in the past, and it has worked quite well.

Alternatively, the .NET framework provides [MAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/acz3y3te%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (and its GUI equivalent [MAGEUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xhctdw55%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) for building and editing ClickOnce manifests *outside* of Visual Studio. Using these tools, while workable, definitely doesn't feel as "smooth" as the IDE-integrated equivalent.

Finally, there's [ClickOnceMore](http://www.clickoncemore.net), which claims to fill much of the same role as MAGEUI, but with a better feature set. Personally, I've never used it, so I can't comment. But there you have it.

Answer (score 4):

I use [this F# script](http://coffeemonitor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ff8e69215d06#CoffeeMonitor/ClickOnce.fsx) to automate calls to the command-line [mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/acz3y3te%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to build a ClickOnce package for my F# project. I first used MAGEUI to build the *.application file and such manually - the script just updates the file list and build number, and creates the zip file.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with deploying an F#-based application with ClickOnce. I finally got it to work. The missing key for me was the following:

The fsc.exe compiler adds a Win32 manifest to the EXE by default. This breaks the ClickOnce deployment as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match). The VS2010 Application page for F# applications does not have an option to "Create application without a manifest". However, the Build page does have an "Other flags" field. I added '--nowin32manifest'. Bang... my ClickOnce deployment started working.

Comment: This bit was crucial for me. This was not the only snag, but it should be highlighted as necessary.