# downloading from a clickonce deployment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, .net-assembly

I publish my vb.Net windows form app to a location in the server for users to install on their machines. It starts running for about 32% and errors with the following message: Application validation did not succeed. Unable to continue.

Details:

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \MyServer\Dep\Databases\Apps\MyApp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly TsLibGen.exe.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

Comment: Did you look at the error log?

Comment: Yes! I did but could not fix it. I copied part of the log in the details section of my question above

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match/5339135

Comment: Mine is VS2012 and I have only one project in my solution