# ClickOnce of WPF : Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I am trying to deploy a WPF application from Visual Studio 2019 .

I see a error :  Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly MyDesktop.Host.exe.

Should the Deployment try to use  MyDesktop.exe instead ?

Thanks,Peter

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338369/1462656

Comment: I read that wiki, but wasn't sure which answer applies to me.  I have a WPF application  MyDesktop.exe which is hosted by MyDesktop.HOST.exe  . In plain English, what does "Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly " mean? If I understand the error message, then i could better fix it.

Comment: having the same issue now. with vs 2017, no problem only happening in vs 2019.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I checked the option "Use application manifiest for trust information" in Publish Options -> Manifests

[image]