# Error with ClickOnce Installation Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am trying to build an Outlook Add-In (OutlookTag) using C# in VS 2013 with the Add-InExpress tool from which I want to call a Windows Forms application (SetTags.exe). I have created a new Add-In Express class library project within the same solution and can create and build the Add-In, which contains reference to the SetTags project. I can also publish the project, but when I try to install it by clicking OutlookTag.Application in the publish folder I get the error "Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly SetTags.exe"

THis seems to be a common problem - I have tried the solutions suggested in

[Error deploying ClickOnce application - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match)

I have found the following:

1) If I set the ClickOnce security setting in SetTags project to Full or partial Trust I get the message "ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'"

2) I cannot set the Manifest setting in Application->Icon and Manifest Settings to "Create Application without a Manifest" because the OutlookTags project is a class library, and the options are greyed out with "Embed manifest with default settings" fixed.

3) Neither changing the Configuration from Debug to Release for both projects or changing the platform of both projects to 32 bit fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I created a new solution and built the Add-In Express add-in in that and was then able to publish and install the Add-In. The problem appears to have been caused by other projects in the first solution.