# ClickOnce - Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest

Tags: wpf, azure-pipelines, clickonce

We have ClickOnce app. It is generated through `Azure Pipelines` with `/p:target=publish`. Because of different environments (even closed networks) there is an web app which you can download `setup.exe` file.

Using `mage.exe` before the download, the `InstallUrl` and `DeploymentUrl` are changed based on the current instance `Base Uri`. This is done with `ASP.NET Core WebAPI`.

Changing deployment url and install URL is done as follows:

```
mage.exe -update {manifestFullPath} -ProviderUrl {finalUri}
```

And changing the URL of `setup.exe`

```
[PATH]\setup.exe /url="BaseUri"
```

where `BaseUri` is pointing to the controller.

Here, I know I have to resign the application manifest of the current version and the base `.application` which I'm doing with `mageui.exe` at the moment.

The `Controller` is invoked, but the moment it has to start downloading the binaries I get

```
Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/troubleshooting-specific-errors-in-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2019#during-update-you-receive-an-error-that-has-the-following-log-entry-the-reference-in-the-deployment-does-not-match-the-identity-defined-in-the-application-manifest).After using `mage.exe` to update the URL, the manifests could have some changes. You could check the `assemblyIdentity ` in deployment and application manifests . You need to make sure that the parameters are in sync.

Comment: Thats the weird part, they are identical.

Comment: It's indeed weird. Check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338369/13464420). You may try to add `/P:UseManifestForTrust="true"` to the Msbuild arguments. Then you could check if it could help.