# install VSTO adds-in with reference to another project

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce

I have a project(A) is a normal winform and another project(B) is a vsto addsin for word
[project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j23W3.png)
my VSTO adds-in references parts of project B
when i make an installation and try to install it the installation gives me an error.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9msf.png)
things i have tried is made a installation for project A and installed it first then tried to install Project B but it gives the same error.

Comment: Are you deploying on a different machine than the one you built the project?  The deploy machine is missing the Microsoft Office Addins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error deploying ClickOnce application - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use advanced installer
i had the same exact problem but was able to fix it with that
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/
this will bundle all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add files from the project A manually to the add-in installer. For your reference, a similar issue is described on the [Error deploying ClickOnce application - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337458/error-deploying-clickonce-application-reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match) thread.

For VSTO based add-in, make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019) article.